# How strong would a human being be if they could turn into living metal?

Tags: magic, super-powers

Let's say that a person, either through superpowers or outright magic, managed to imbue their body with [the strength of steel](http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/Metal_Mimicry), like [Colossus](http://marvel.com/universe/Colossus_(Piotr_Rasputin)) from X-Men who becomes *"living steel"*.

If this actually happened: how would human physical power be effected? How much more could the now *steel person* lift, compared to a normal human being?

Comment: As strong as the plot demands. This is not a question that has a determined answer from the information provided.  See also [this](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37993/if-the-moon-were-made-of-cheese-what-would-maxwells-laws-become) question.

Comment: I do think this is too broad because there is no actual basis for any answers.  Is there any reason the "lift around 75 tons" number is not enough of an answer?

Comment: Would you mind defining which variety of handwavium you have in mind for this question and its properties? This would be critical in any well-formed answer.

Comment: @Frostfyre The how doesn't really matter and I don't know the exact terminology to be precise. If human body gained the resilience of  steel how would that effect strength?

Comment: "If this thing that can't happen happened, what would happen?"

Comment: @ckersch This question has the tags of magic and superpowers because we are in the realm of the fantastical. That said given steels's strength compared to human tissues, I wondered if a person really could pull of the Colossus trick how much of a boot would it really provided.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on what you mean by "turning into metal".

In weight-lifting, the muscular power and the physical fortitude of a person are the salient factors.

Metallic bodies can probably support more weight if their joints can be locked-up. (Imagine weight being put on a metal pillar versus a pillar of flesh and bones)

However, having metal body parts do not necessitate muscular power. If a human being have their flesh replaced with equal volumes of metal and have the flesh operated by motors with the same power output as their former muscles, that person would probably collapse under their own weight.

If metallic body means the muscular power (or its new equivalent) is increased so as to support and move it as though the body is unchanged, then the power would be multiplied by an amount roughly equal to this:$$\frac{\text{density of metal}}{\text{density of flesh}}$$

any excess power can then be used in lifting weights.

Comment: I mean the latter, a person is now metal and has all the power required to move about normally. To be more specific I was wondering how the transition to a stronger substance would effect human physical power.

Answer (score 3):

They probably would have trouble moving.

Lets assume a few things - if this is a surface transformation, their muscles would need to adapt to a heavier 'skin' without the stretchiness of human skin. They'd have to overcome weight *and* friction of their skin plates, or have a surface coating that is barely at the liquid/metal transition phase.

If its the latter, basically anything hot enough would just pierce through.

If muscles were transformed as well, they'd have to *instantaneously* change to another mechanism and physical material. The closest thing to muscles is memory metal and that's complicated, not very efficient, and relies on a different mechanism from muscles - heat rather than power.

Also, having your lungs turn to metal would deprive you of oxygen and you'd die, assuming your brains didn't turn to metal as well. I have no idea how having a steel brain would work.

So. Not very strong at all, but you'd make a lovely statue for pigeons to roost.

Comment: Given steels's strength compared to human tissues, I wondered if a person really could pull of the Colossus's trick how much of a boot would it really provided.