# How plausible is an Alcubierre drive, really?

Tags: internal-consistency, physics

Like on a scale of one to ten, how plausible are Alcubierre drives in terms of our current understanding of physics? Plausible enough to be considered "hard sci-fi", or are they just another form of handwave like hyperspace?

This isn't asking about how the science behind the Alcubierre drive works (except as needed for other parts of an answer). Rather, it is about whether and how an Alcubierre drive can work in a hard-science level fiction work.

Comment: I consider to be a very high probability that we will be able to make such a thing. Unfortunately there is a good chance it wouldn't be useable as a form of travel due to some of the possible secondary effects like having to be on rails and carrying high energy particles with which would end up just making it a very expensive and time consuming way to shoot a planet with the worlds largest most powerful 1 target cannon...

Comment: hard sci-fi, 100% possible theoretically, Even problems with energy can be managed by creating small pocket space, but I have my own reservation in it ever being  practical.

Comment: Hi Z.Schroeder. I'm afraid your original phrasing was an almost open invitation to opinion-based answers, so I tried to reword it in a way that retains what I believe was your intent, but does so while not as much seeking peoples' *opinions*. If you feel I changed your intent then by all means do feel free to edit further, but please do your best to allow us to objectively judge answers given on how well they answer the question. *Every answer is equally valid* and *open-ended, hypothetical question* are both [specifically discouraged](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: One issue you will either have to lampshade or flat-out handwave away in your story is *causality*...

Comment: @JaredSmith In all fairness, that doesn't really impact whether the technology itself is plausible; only its consequences.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling FTL violates causality. If causality can be violated, *our **fundamental** understanding of the universe is wrong*. Since the OP framed the question in terms of sci-fi hardness, it needs to be addressed somehow.

Comment: I thought Alcubierre drives didn't violate causality due to the way they function?

Comment: @Z.Schroeder As was pointed out also in a comment to a4android's answer, the effect on causality remains the same regardless of the mechanics of how FTL is achieved; all that is required is superluminal transmission speeds. Really, do read up on the [tachyonic antitelephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone). The Wikipedia article isn't that bad, and I wouldn't be surprised if it's touched on in physics textbooks also. See also [searching for `antitelephone` on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=antitelephone).

Comment: For a more in-depth discussion on Alcubierre drive and causality, I recommend [How does “warp drive” not violate Special Relativity causality constraints?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119522/14091) on Physics SE over discussion in the comments here.

Comment: [LENTZ](https://www.centauri-dreams.org/2021/03/11/ftl-thoughts-on-a-new-paper-by-erik-lentz/) drive now.  No negamatter required!

Answer (score 38):

The only real issue with Alcubierre drives is that they require negative matter to work.  Negative matter (NOT antimatter, which is very real) is a hypothetical substance that generates negative gravity; i.e. that pushes matter away from it.  In the "rubber sheet" analogy, where gravity is depicted as depressions in the fabric of space-time, negative matter creates "bumps" instead.

While mathematically possible under the geometry of special relativity, negative matter has never been observed, nor is there any place in the Standard Model of particle physics where it is expected to occur.  So the big issue is, is negative matter possible?  If so, an Alcubierre drive is simply a question of energy and engineering.  If not, the drive is not possible.

Alcubierre drives are maybe around a 7.5 in sci-fi hardness - not a completely magical hand-wave but still requires an imaginary particle to work.  They are more plausible than wormholes (which also require negative matter, as well as the need to 'tear' space-time) and less plausible than Dyson spheres (which require no imaginary physics, only scale and energy).

They *are* one of the least hand-wavey methods of FTL travel, so if your story needs FTL travel while remaining as plausible as possible an Alcubierre drive is probably the way to go.

Comment: The Alcubierre drive isn't "mathematically possible under the geometry of special relativity" it is a theoretical solution of general relativity. Apart from that, your answer is generally on the money.

Comment: Antimatter *could be* negative matter, but we haven't produced enough of it to find out. (I.e it goes boom before we have time to see which way it falls.)

Comment: I would like to point out that negative density is possible - see the Casimir effect. Now of course the microscopic force created in a lab is far from a lump of negative matter you can stuff into an FTL drive, but the principle is there. I don't know if what we've observed qualifies as "matter", but if it does, then your claim of "negative matter has never been observed" is wrong. (IIRC they even made a nanoturbine powered by the Casimir effect, but I can't find any references now so it might have been speculation and I'm just misremembering.)

Comment: According to this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive), the requirement isn't for "negative matter" but for *negative energy density*, which was thought to require *exotic* matter, but more recently it has been thought that a negative energy density can be produced without need of any exotic matter.

Comment: Doesn't negative matter potentially violate causality (because of the Alcubierre drive) making it logically impossible?

Comment: Not negative matter but exotic matter. "Exotic matter is a hypothetical kind of matter that has both a negative energy density and a negative pressure or tension that exceeds the energy density. All known forms of matter have positive energy density and pressures or tensions that are always less than the energy density in magnitude. In a stretched rubber band, for example, the energy density is 100 trillion times greater than the tension." Its existence isn't canceled by potential causality violation. It may simply not exist if negative energy densities can't be sustained.

Comment: «Antimatter could be negative matter, but we haven't produced enough of it to find out» **wrong**: antimatter + matter pair production takes 2× the energy of the particle to produce, not zero. Likewise for anniliation.

Comment: Matter with negative mass would be very hard to obtain, even if possible. Assuming gravitational mass = inertial mass, negative mass makes objects respond in the opposite way to a force. Since F = MA, and M is negative, a positive force makes a negative acceleration. So you push an object with negative mass. It pushes back. The negative gravity of negative mass pushes a positive mass object away, but pulls the negative mass object closer to it as well, so the two objects chase each other and keep accelerating across the universe.

Comment: I'm intrigued that there's apparently an index of sci-fi hardness.

Comment: @SigmaOri Diamonds are a 10 on the sci-fi hardness scale: definitely proven to exist. :-)

Comment: Negative energy is [not necessarily required](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6382/abe692) for an Alcubierre drive.  However, without it you would need to produce about 1 million trillion trillion modern nuclear reactors worth of energy.

Comment: Another possible workaround is to manipulate *vacuum energy* ⁠— the latent energy of empty space.  We can already do this on a small scale: when two metal plates are placed a few microns apart, the wavelengths of the virtual particles/antiparticles which make up the vacuum energy cannot fit between them, creating negative pressure and pushing the plates together.  If you can create a large region of reduced vacuum energy, then you can negatively curve space without negative energy, but instead a relative decrease in energy compared to normal empty space.

Answer (score 19):

The Alcubierre drive is theoretically plausible. It is a mathematically correct solution of the Einstein field equations. Its main problem is that the warped path through spacetime for its trajectory has to be set up before it travels. This makes it more like a FTL railway train than an independent vehicle like a spacecraft.

Segei Krashnikov, another theoretician, was dubious about the effectiveness of the Alcubierre metric and he proposed his own solution the Krashnikov. A spaceship travelling to Alpha Centauri creates the warped spacetime path as it travels to Alpha Centauri at sublight speed. On its return journey the spaceship travels along the Krashnikov tube arriving home faster than if it had travelled at less than lightspeed. Effectively that's faster than lightspeed, but only for the return leg of its round trip.

This example is to illustrate the fact that while the Alcubierre drive is theoretically plausible and mathematically correct, not every scientist working in general relativity accepts the concept.

There is also the exotic matter issue, because it requires negative energy densities to keep open the warp bubble. There are problems about the possible of causality violation, because if Alcubierre drive vessels travel first one way and come back again this allows trip into its own past. OK, this can be regarded as a bonus. With FTL travel, you get time-travel as a free accessory. Still it's a worry for those who hold causality dear.

If a writer was using an Alcubierre drive for their FTL spaceships it is scientifically plausible and can be considered as almost a hard-science concept.

Comment: I thought the Alcubierre drive was one of the FTL solutions without time-travel, since it doesn't actually move faster than light at any point? - Being quicker than light at your destination doesn't mean you can go to your past - if the light had to take a longer journey. -> I can travel faster than light: I send a laser beam to the mirror on the moon so it comes back 3 steps in front of me - and while the light is travelling I do the three steps and are there faster than light, but without time-travel. And the Alcubierre is essentially that

Comment: @Falco Causality violations are an inevitable result of FTL travel, regardless of how it is achieved. There's a great discussion here: http://www.physicsguy.com/ftl/html/FTL_part4.html and see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone It doesn't matter if you're "moving faster than light", only that you (or information) are arriving outside the light cone that defines normal causality. Substitute the tachyonic telephone messages with messengers travelling by Alcubierre-powered shuttle, and the paradox remains.

Comment: «Being quicker than light at your destination doesn't mean you can go to your past» yes, it does.  See [this answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/46873/are-there-any-ways-to-allow-some-form-of-ftl-travel-without-allowing-time-travel/47038#47038).

Comment: @JDługosz But that's simply not true, since light is affected by gravity and bends/slows down around big gravity wells, you can create a real world scenario where a straight light-ray is slower at a destination than a longer way around the gravity well. This doesn't lead to time travel.

Comment: @IMSoP But if I fold space, the resulting target is simply closer to me, the way is simply shorter and so my space-time position will be well defined inside my light cone. It just happens that other light-rays may travel a longer way by taking a big detour (the straight line without travelling through folded space) - just because I can send light on a detour to a target doesn't result in time-travel

Comment: @Falco We're not talking about making light slower so that you can overtake it, we're talking about travelling between two points such that your average speed in some frame of reference exceeds *c*. By my understanding of the linked article, if the Defiant and Enterprise leave DS9 in different directions, and can each send shuttles faster than *c*, the Defiant can send the Enterprise a message about its own future by exploiting relativity. It doesn't matter how those shuttles travel, as long as they arrive.

Comment: @falco you should ask on [physics.se] to get a detailed explaination of this scenareo and a more rigorous statement of what it means re outrun light and causality.

Comment: @Falco I think you're taking "faster than light" too literally; it doesn't actually mean "able to overtake a light-beam", it means "a velocity exceeding *c*". The point of an FTL drive is to make a 500 light-year journey and back with less than 1000 years having elapsed on the ground when you return. If you can do that, you can build a tachyonic antitelephone, and violate causality.

Comment: @IMSop As far as I can tell all FTL-Causality paradoxes stem from interacting with other frames of reference, which have a propabilistic speed compared to our own. So only work, if I can interact with the other observer instantly despite him having a vastly different velocity. If out FTL drive allowed us to change position, but not velocity we would then need to accelerate to interact and this would cost enough time so we were up to time again...

Comment: @JDługosz So if we only allow our Alcubierre Drive to work for FTL-Travel in respect to a single static privileged frame of reference, we should have no causality problems whatsoever.

Comment: «propabilistic speed»?  Right, it takes more than one reference frame, when the physics of the FTL drive are the same in any frame.  Alice and Bob *can* interact while still passing each other at high speed, by sending messages.  How much time you must wait to prevent the issue is exactly what normal light-speed transit would have done.

Comment: As @IMSoP explains, the issue is *getting there*, by any means, where *there* is a spacelike interval (outside your light cone). However, with gravitational warping of spacetime due to massive stars, calculating the interval (the shortest possible way) is more difficult. Your earlier example just means the light wasn’t taking the shortest available path.

Comment: @Falco Right, that is a common suggestion for how to solve the problem, for instance some form of special "subspace frame of reference", in which everyone can agree that Alice's FTL drive arrived before Bob's departed. That is *not*, however, directly implied by Alcubierre's theory, based on what I've read about it. You can have 2 of {relativity, causality, FTL}. A "privileged frame of reference" resolves that by discarding (replacing) relativity, but Alcubierre was working entirely within relativity.

Comment: @IMSoP thank you for the insight. I thought the kind of space-folding which the Alcubierre Drive relies on is only possible with some kind of privileged reference frame, a static background on which space happens

Comment: @IMSoP A "privileged frame of reference" doesn't resolve the paradoxes by discarding (replacing) relativity, it modifies relativity so the SR framework remains except the First Postulate that there  are no preferred reference frames has been dropped. The Alcubierre metric is grounded in general relativity. While SR is the basis for arguments against FTL, GR has this bad fact of letting them back in again. It is hoped quantum gravity will settle the matter, probably in the negative. No FTL allowed.

Comment: @IMSoP The Hinson triad of relativity, causality & FTL, choose any two is a fun concept. If it hardens into dogma, the mirth fades. Let's examine them. FTL, if it existed, would be a physical fact. Relativity is a human theory about nature. It may be incomplete, this means it could be replaced by a more complete theory. Causality is more a just-so story than a theory. Scientists are working to review its nature. The Hinson triad mightn't be immutable. Nature will always have the last laugh. This doesn't mean real FTL, just we don't have all the answers -- not yet.

Comment: @a4android I think we're just arguing semantics now. Let's rephrase: you can have three of FTL, relativity as currently defined, and causality as we know it. A theory of relativity modified to include a privileged reference frame would no longer be "relativity as currently defined", and a tachyonic antitelephone would not be "causality as we know it". If nature turns out to allow FTL but maintain causality, we *have* to modify our theory of relativity, so we have only kept two out of the three.

Comment: @IMSoP I understand, but aren't interested in semantics. There are research papers with revised ideas about causality. SR & FTL leads to causality problems, but if, IF, revised causality wipes out causal violations, then it might come with all three. The big IF is to say we don't know how that will turn out. I'd bet quantum gravity will absolutely block FTL. Currently general relativity lets in four hypothetical forms of FTL. Perhaps nature doesn't mind time machines. I love it when research goes places you don't expect.

Comment: @a4android I don't count "revising one of the three things to have a new meaning" as "keeping one of the three", that's all. But yes, "some form of relativity + some form of causality + FTL" might well be possible.

Answer (score 5):

There is a weak sense in which the Alcubierre geometry is a "solution" of general relativity. But **anything is a "solution" of general relativity** in this same weak sense. General relativity says that the matter distribution in a spacetime is related to the geometry of the spacetime in a certain way. You can take *any* spacetime geometry (as long as it's twice differentiable), plug it into that equation, get a matter distribution, and then say "if only we could make this matter distribution happen, we could make this spacetime geometry happen", with exactly the same plausibility as the Alcubierre geometry.

For example, suppose you want the Sun to suddenly disappear. I don't mean that it accelerates away, or blows up, or anything like that. It just disappears. Its gravitational field goes to zero, planets fly away in a straight line, etc.

It's easy to do this. You just take a spacetime metric with the Sun in it (the Schwarzschild interior and exterior solutions stitched together), and a spacetime metric without the Sun (Minkowski space), interpolate between them with a smooth (or at least twice differentiable) function of time, and plug that into the Einstein equation. The result will not make much sense: you'll find that the Sun's mass flows out to infinity through a region with zero mass density. Exotic matter to the rescue! By introducing negative-mass matter, you can counter the mass of the outflowing matter and make the total mass density zero in the region where general relativity says it has to be zero.

It's important to understand that this matter isn't "exotic" just in having negative mass. It's exotic in that it doesn't follow *any* physical laws. It just shows up out of nowhere (literally, out of vacuum) during the disappearance of the sun, then disappears into nowhere. It isn't even subject to cause and effect, much less any more specific physical theory.

The same is true of the exotic matter in Alcubierre's spacetime. It is not a "warp drive", because that would imply that the exotic matter could come from the spaceship that's going to ride the bubble. It can't, because the exotic matter on the outside of the bubble is spacelike. That means that either it travels locally outside the light cone, or it arises independently everywhere along the path. The first case would make the solution uninteresting, since if you can travel outside the light cone then you don't need a general-relativistic warp drive to circumvent light speed. So the exotic matter can't come from the ship. In Alcubierre's geometry, it appears miraculously out of vacuum just before the ship arrives, then disappears into vacuum after it leaves. General relativity is perfectly fine with this. As soon as you add any additional physical laws, it's ruled out.

People have speculated about exotic matter guns that could pre-distribute exotic matter with the right properties. You could likewise speculate about a Sun-vanishing gun. The argument in both cases is "Well, based on everything that we think we know about the world, this is impossible. But if you ignore some of that, the remaining premises aren't strong enough to prove it's impossible any more. So maybe it's possible!" Yes, maybe. All science is subject to revision. But based on everything we know right now, the Alcubierre drive is as scientific as time travel. (In fact, it could be used for time travel.)

Comment: Can you add some citation to your specific interpretation of the exotic matter involved?

Comment: Citations for exotic matter include negative energy density  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_energy, exotic matter categories  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_matter, and the Alcubierre drive itself https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive

Answer (score 0):

The Alcubierre Drive is indeed possible from a scientific point of view.  Exotic matter is not hypothetical, it has being observed, but is just very difficult to produce and it is almost impossible for us, right now at least, to make it in amounts large enough.  Also, Alcubierre proposed that Casimir vacuum might work instead of exotic matter, for that matter (no pun intended). Whether it violates causality or not that was debated somewhere else.

To me, the real issue is more about practicality. The Alcubierre Drive generates a lot of practical problems, apart from costs.  For example:

- Maybe no living being can survive inside the bubble do to the extreme amount of heat and Hawkings radiation. Of course this does not precludes for sending intelligent robots to explore the cosmos instead which is a pretty good idea for a sci-fi setting.
  -The planet-destroyer shock wave of particles at the arrival.
- How to maneuver and stop the vessel if the people inside can’t interact with the universe outside the bubble. Etc.

But any talented sci-fi writer can find clever ways to overcome these issues.

Another thing that most writers overlook is that most of the problems I mentioned do not happen in subluminal speeds, and that makes the Alcubierre Drive interesting for a non-FTL setting becoming the by far fastest way to travel, for example, inside the Solar System.

Comment: "Exotic matter is not hypothetical, it has being observed" - have I missed a Nobel Prize announcement recently? It would be perhaps the biggest revolution in theoretical physics since the General Theory of Relativity.

Comment: the specific exotic matter required has **not** been observed anywhere.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/04/170417095534.htm

Answer (score 0):

Alcubierre drive is a sound way, under the current laws of physics, to explain a valid way of travel faster-than-light and the only way (unless wormholes are ever observed) to “break” the speed of light. However, and this is a big however, what makes AD improbable or implausible for our current civilization is how to make it work. For it we would need whether exotic matter with negative mass (which still hypothetical) or harnessing somehow the Casimir effect which causes negative mass. Both things are not impossible, but we still don’t know how to do either yet. So, maybe tomorrow someone would find the way or maybe never.

So, if for example you’re working on science fiction book and wanted it to be hard sci-fi, the “hardish” way to make FTL is with the AD, but for a lot of people even in that case is then no longer “hard” sci-fi (but this is kind of subjective).

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible, by any means, to send information from point A to point B faster than the speed of light in a vacuum. I will give you a simple proof of this:

Einstein constructed Special Relativity using thought experiments that involved clocks positioned at various points in space and information flowing  between these clocks. The information flowing between these clocks has to be the fastest possible speed at which information can be communicated, which happens to be the speed of light in a vacuum. If there is a faster max speed by which to communicate information between clocks in space then Einstein would have had to use that faster speed. So for example, if the max speed is 2c instead of c then Einstein would have had to use 2c in his relativistic equation instead of c, otherwise the relativistic equations would produce incorrect results. So let's take the equation E = MC^2. This equation has been experimentally verified to many decimal places https://news.mit.edu/2005/emc2. It uses the speed of light. Therefore the speed of light must be the fastest possible speed to transmit information. If the max speed is 2c then the equation would have to be rewritten as E = 4MC^2.

Now you might say that an Alcubierre drive does not operate in normal space and therefore is exempt from the light speed limitation. But this is not so. It doesn't matter how information is transferred between points A and B in normal space. You could put an Alcubierre drive between points A and B in normal space, A spaceship will start from point A, use an Alcubierre drive after it has left point A and then shutoff the Alcubierre drive and reenter normal space before it reaches point B. In doing so it will outrace a beam of light that started at point A and headed towards point B. Einstein could have used this Alcubierre drive in his thought experiments.

So the fact that the equation E = MC^2, and all the other relativistic equations that use the speed of light, produces correct results proves that the speed of light IS the fastest possible speed at which to transmit information (and astronauts) in space.

Comment: I think you are a bit confused on one aspect, but that's totally fine.

There is something that is moving/expanding faster than the speed of light. Space. The expansion of space using the measure of redshift in order to calculate relative speed in reference to us, the observer shows that indeed, some of the farthest astronomical objects billions of light years away are moving away from us faster than light.

The reason this does not violate Einstein's special relativity is because, in between the two objects(us and a distant astronomical object) new space is appearing.

Comment: The alcubierre drive essentially compresses spacetime in front of the craft, and extends spacetime behind it, in a shape of a depression and extension. The craft is not 'moving' in the common sense, the space around it is manipulated in such a way that the space, containing the craft, is going from point a to point b.

Comment: However the exotic matter/energy required for the function of the drive has not yet been observed. So still fringe physics, although not implausible.

Comment: @Sync actually exotic matter was observed recently

Comment: @Daniel where and when? Link?

Comment: If you mean the casmir effect that's not it lmao

Comment: @Sync www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/04/170417095534.htm

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is going to be more of a rant against the concept of "hard sci-fi" than a strict answer to your question, but asking people now in the 21st century to guess at the viability of the Alcubierre drive would be like asking someone from Da Vinci's time how plausible it would be for a helicopter to ever really be built. They, and we, simply do not have sufficient information to answer the question. In fact, the only thing we can be certain of is that we can be certain that we can't be certain.

Answer (score -3):

It depends on your definition of "plausible". I would take it to mean anything not disproven by established fact or available evidence. There is no need for a working demonstration test article to exist just to make a claim for plausibility.

Consider a few established realities of our modern world:

- jet airliners
- nuclear powered submarines
- humans have walked on the Moon
- smartphones and all the wonderful tricks they can do
- GPS
- CGI movie effects

and how plausible any of that would have been to a Jules Verne era audience.

Consider also that NASA has taken the Alcubierre drive seriously enough to fund related projects at their Advanced Propulsion Physics Laboratory.

On the other hand, Star Trek style artificial gravity, superluminal ("subspace") communication, force fields, phasers and Vulcan telepathy are all far less plausible. Nothing in our current understanding of physics permits the existence of any of them. Although teleportation (a "transporter" in Trek-speak) is theoretically possible and even demonstrated to a limited degree at a quantum mechanical level, it is nevertheless implausible on a human scale because of all the difficulties which arise. Without a whole new understanding of physics, none of this belongs in hard sci-fi.

What may have been seen as totally implausible a century and a half ago is now part of our everyday world. Who could have predicted the wireless revolution or the internet at a time when there was no such thing as radio, telephone, or anything more computationally sophisticated than a mechanical adding machine?

Even if it turns out that an Alcubierre drive is impossible to build/operate, it has passed the threshold of plausibility not just in hard sci-fi but even respectable science because:

- the laws of physics don't forbid it
- establishment funding has been applied toward its investigation
- related experiments have produced some interesting results, even if inconclusive

Comment: To be fair, everything you listed is possible, it just depends on how many caveats you want to give it. Quantum teleportation is possible, as you said, but creates an absolutely ridiculous number of problems when scaled up. Artificial gravity can be created, but it's more of an illusion of gravity created by centrifugal force. With some incredible but still plausible advances in energy generation and miniaturization, phasers could be feasible in the far future. And telepathy only requires a few cybernetic implants that allow you to communicate wirelessly with other people's implants.

Comment: @Z.Schroeder I was referring to devices/phenomena as depicted - artificial gravity handwaved as "gravity plating" in later shows; handheld weapons capable of emitting an adjustable energy beam which can stun, kill or vaporize according to a setting; telepathy by means of some natural ability (not artificial implant) between a "telepath" and an otherwise un-endowed subject.

Comment: There are two sorts of plausible. "Could you explain how it works (fundamentals) to a physicist" and "Could you explain how to make one to an engineer". The physics of a jet engine would have been pretty clear to Newton. The physics of anything nuclear or electronic would not have been. Travelling to the moon and walking on it would not have been physically implausible to Newton, but the engineering would be quite another matter!